# ClientLoginException from appcfg.sh

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication

I am attempting to upload a new version of a Google App Engine Application with `appcfg.sh
 upload` but get the following exception:

```
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ClientLoginServerConnection$ClientLoginException: 
Email "...@gmail.com" and password do not match.
```

When prompted, I use the same Email address (`...@gmail.com`) and password that works just fine for logging into Google Developers Console e.g. using Safari.

Could this be a problem with my terminal settings? (I am using OS X Yosemite. If I type the password on the command line it appears as expected.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend the "password-less login with oauth2" explained at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Password-less_login_with_OAuth2 .

Just run `appcfg.py --oauth2` with whatever command you require, and you'll be asked, once, to authorize your Google userid in your browser; then, the credentials are stored in file `.appcfg_oauth2_tokens`, and used thereafter.  The page above goes into details about how to control the authorization process more finely, but, for me, the simple approach I'm summarizing here has been quite satisfactory.